# Как осуществить поиск в базе данных?

Tags: javascript, java, html

Проблема в том что он осуществляет поиск на 1 странице, а надо чтобы по всем.
По сути поиск по тегам, должен быть такой же как на этом сайте

**search.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#anythingSearch").on("keyup", function () {
        const value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("#tagsTable *").filter(function () {
            $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
    });
});
```

**вывод тегов**

```
writeTags() {

        $('#tagsTable').children().remove()

        this.tags.then(function (response) {
            for (var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++) {
                $('#tagsTable').append(
                    " <div class=\"child\">"
                    + "<p class=\"media\">"
                    + "<a href=\"#\" class=\"mb-1\">" + response.items[i].name + "</a>"
                    + "<div><small>" + response.items[i].description + "</small></div>"
                    + "<p>"
                    + "<div class=\"child2\"><small class=\"text-muted\">" + response.items[i].countQuestion + " вопросов" + "</small></div>"
                    + "<div class=\"child2\">"
                    + "<small><a href=\"#\" class=\"text-muted\">" + response.items[i].countQuestionToDay + " задано сегодня, " + "</a></small>"
                    + "<small><a href=\"#\" class=\"text-muted\">" + response.items[i].countQuestionToWeek + " за неделю" + "</a></small>"
                    + "</div> </p> </div>");
            }
        })
        this.tagsPageNavigation()
    }
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что у вас нет нигде запроса, сам js-браузера ничего не знает о ваших страницах.

Comment: Я это понял, хотелось бы узнать как сделать

Comment: В зависимости от задачи, можно использовать как чистый `XMLHttpRequest`, так и от сторонних разработок, по типу `jquery` - у него есть объекты `$.get, $.post`, всеми известный `$.ajax`.

Comment: А возможно ли `response.items[i].name` передать в `$("#tagsTable *")`  ?

Comment: Ну да, если `input` то так: `$('#tagsTable input[name="'+response.items[i].name+'"]')`, вообщем смотря что делаете.